# Dynamically adjust sticky toolbar's position in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, position, sticky, ckeditor5

Here's the [Classic editor demo page](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html). Please add some [text](https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html) until it's height is bigger than your screen. Then if you click inside the editor and start scrolling down, you'll see that the toolbar becomes sticky when it hits the top of the page.
It uses [`viewportTopOffset` property](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_panel_sticky_stickypanelview-StickyPanelView.html#member-viewportTopOffset).

How can I change the toolbars position on window resize or if the height of the fixed header changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a known issue. You can re-report it there or give a reaction to increase its priority: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/issues/405.